# ask about "test driven development with python" chapter 5

Tags: python, django, testing, tdd

page 63 ~ 66

I run the code

```
python manage.py test
```

the error message is

```
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
FF.
======================================================================
FAIL: test_home_page_can_save_a_POST_request     (lists.tests.HomePageTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/hanminsoo/Documents/TDD_test/TDD_Test/superlists/lists/tests.py", line 33, in test_home_page_can_save_a_POST_request
self.assertEqual(response.content.strip().decode(), expected_html)
AssertionError: '<htm[381 chars]     신규 작업 아이템\n        </td>\n      </tr>\n  [28 chars]tml>' != '<htm[381 chars]     \n        </td>\n      </tr>\n    </table[21 chars]l>\n'

======================================================================
FAIL: test_home_page_returns_correct_html (lists.tests.HomePageTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/hanminsoo/Documents/TDD_test/TDD_Test/superlists/lists/tests.py", line 18, in test_home_page_returns_correct_html
self.assertEqual(response.content.decode(), expected_html)
AssertionError: '<htm[381 chars]     None\n        </td>\n      </tr>\n    </t[25 chars]l>\n' != '<htm[381 chars]     \n        </td>\n      </tr>\n    </table[21 chars]l>\n'

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 3 tests in 0.011s

FAILED (failures=2)
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

here is my code -(home.html)

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>To-Do lists</title>
  </head>
  <body>
        <h1>Your To-Do list</h1>
    <form method="POST">
      <input name="item_text" id="id_new_item" placeholder="작업 아이템 입력" />
      {% csrf_token %}

    </form>
    <table id="id_list_table">
      <tr>
        <td>
          {{ new_item_text }}
        </td>
      </tr>
</table>
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

# Create your views here.
def home_page(request):
    return render(
            request,
            'home.html',
            {
                'new_item_text': request.POST.get('item_text')
                }
            )
```

test.py

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import resolve
from django.test import TestCase
from django.http import HttpRequest
from django.template.loader import render_to_string

from lists.views import home_page

class HomePageTest(TestCase):

    def test_root_url_resolves_to_home_page_view(self):
        found = resolve('/')
        self.assertEqual(found.func, home_page)

    def test_home_page_returns_correct_html(self):
        request = HttpRequest()
        response = home_page(request)
        expected_html = render_to_string('home.html', request=request)
        self.assertEqual(response.content.decode(), expected_html)
        self.assertIn(b'<title>To-Do lists</title>', response.content.strip())

    def test_home_page_can_save_a_POST_request(self):
        request = HttpRequest()
        request.method = 'POST'
        request.POST['item_text'] = '신규 작업 아이템'

        response = home_page(request)

        self.assertIn('신규 작업 아이템', response.content.strip().decode())
        expected_html = render_to_string(
                'home.html',
                request=request
                )
        self.assertEqual(response.content.strip().decode(), expected_html)
```

first, my solution is add code '' in views.py

```
'<htm[381 chars] None\n </td>\n </tr>\n</t[25 chars]l>\n' != '<htm[381 chars] \n </td>\n </tr>\n </table[21 chars]l>\n
```

1

```
'new_item_text': request.POST.get('item_text')
```

is changed

```
'new_item_text': request.POST.get('item_text', '')
```

so, I solved one problem

'test_home_page_returns_correct_html'

but I can't found second problem...

```
'<htm[381 chars] 신규 작업 아이템\n </td>\n </tr>\n [28 chars]tml>' != '<htm[381 chars] \n </td>\n </tr>\n </table[21 chars]l>\n'
```

why it dosen't add '신규 작업 아이템'??

please help me!

Comment: Which Django version are you using?

Comment: I used django 1.9.5, python 3.5.1 @Alasdair

Comment: Try the lineself.assertEqual(response.content.strip().decode(), expected_html) without the .strip()

Comment: oh,, I solved my problem. i try add the code '{'new_item_text': '신규 작업 아이템'}' in 'test_home_page_can_save_a_POST_request(self)' thank you everyone!